# Same pattern different route

Tags: php, url, yii2, uri, http-verbs

How can I defined two same URI that have two difference method to be called ?
For example :

```
 'owners/<user_id:\d+>/pets' => 'pets/index', //using GET
 'owners/<user_id:\d+>/pets' => 'pets/create',//using POST
```

I try this code below :

```
 'GET owners/<user_id:\d+>/pets' => 'pets/index',
 'POST owners/<user_id:\d+>/pets' => 'pets/create',
```

but my problem is that if I have this code It always display 404 not found instead of 405?

Note that I already added this on my behaviors :

```
'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'index'  => ['get'],
                    'create'  => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this (in this order):

```
'POST owners/<user_id:\d+>/pets' => 'pets/create',
'owners/<user_id:\d+>/pets' => 'pets/index',
```

Comment: Hello, I will try this later, can you give me other details?